# Android: How to get current Wifi encryption?

Tags: android, encryption, connection, wifi

I have a listener listening for connectivity changes, especially from GSM to WIFI.
Now I would like to log which WIFIs the user connects to, especially the encryption type (none, WEP, WPA, WPA2, ...) of the WIFI.

The listener works perfectly, but I can't find any way to get the current Wifi's encryption type.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [WifiManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html) to obtain details of the current connection, and then obtain a [WifiConfiguration](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiConfiguration.html) which should give you further information.

```
WifiManager wifiManager= (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wi = WifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
if( wi != null )
{
    WifiConfiguration activeConfig = null;
    for( WifiConfiguration conn : wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks() )
    {
        if( conn.status == WifiConfiguration.Status.CURRENT )
        {
            activeConfig = conn;
            break;
        }
    }
    if( activeConfig != null )
    {
        // Analyse encryption of connected network here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I found that, but it seems the only way to get the WifiConfiguration seems to be WindowManager.getConfiguredNetworks() which returns a List<WifiConfiguration>. I could now get the current Wifi i.e. via the BSSID, or is the currently connected Network always the first one in the list?

Comment: Thanks for your help, Mark. I just found another way to get current wifi, via the WifiConfiguration.status flag. This has to equal WifiConfiguration.Status.CURRENT

Comment: Nice find! I wasn't aware of that. It should make the code slightly more efficient. Please "accept" the answer if you've found it helpful.

Comment: Can you please tell, how exactly you extract encryption from WifiConfiguration object? I looked through allowed* BitSets, but they differ only for WEP/OPEN/WPA networks, for WPA and WPA2 all fields are the same. How could I differ WPA from WPA2 networks?

Comment: @Tobi WifiConfiguration.status does not work property on samsung galaxy tab 7 (android 4.1.2). Resurns list of networks but only with flags ENABLED or DISABLED, not return status CURRENT solution from Mark works fine

Comment: @Mark Allison there are 2 small errors in your code. For one I think it should be WifiConfiguration in line 5 and there is a ) missing for the second if clause.
Thanks for the code!